# Refresh my query results from my table view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO


ALTER VIEW [dbo].[pais2k1view]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
                  RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.last) AS LastName, RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.first) AS         Firstname, RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.middle) AS Middlename, RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.rank) AS rank, 
                  RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.badge_no) AS badge_no, RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.tin) AS TIN, CONVERT(char(10), dbo.Gen_info.birthdate, 110) AS birthdate, dbo.Gen_info.hair, 
                  dbo.Gen_info.eyes, RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.blood) AS Blood, dbo.Gen_info.height, dbo.Gen_info.weight, dbo.Gen_info.marks, dbo.dependent.name, 
                  dbo.dependent.address, dbo.dependent.phone_no, dbo.dependent.dep_contact, dbo.dependent.dep_phone, dbo.Gen_info.acct_no, dbo.Gen_info.unit AS RDO_Code, 
                  dbo.Gen_info.fstatus, dbo.dependent.tag1, RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.first) + ' ' + RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.middle) + ' ' + RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.last) AS Fullname, 
                  RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.last) + RTRIM(dbo.Gen_info.first) AS Photolink, dbo.Unit.abbvr AS unit
FROM         dbo.Gen_info WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.dependent WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Gen_info.link = dbo.dependent.link LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.Unit WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.Gen_info.unit = dbo.Unit.unit
WHERE     (dbo.dependent.fstatus = 0) AND (dbo.dependent.tag1 = 1) AND (dbo.Gen_info.fstatus = 0)
```

I'm using sql management studio and this is my alter view, how do i add a refresh command to this line so that the view will always reflect the most updated records

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do that. Views are not tables, they are predefined queries.

When you select from a view, SQL Server executes the view's query at that time.

You can test this by creating your view, selecting from it, then adding a row to a base table and selecting from the view again.

Answer (score 0):

If you make changes to the underlying tables you will need to refresh your view to see the reflected changes,  but I'm pretty sure you can't do that in an alter statement.

```
sp_refreshview [dbo].[pais2k1view]
```

You then could either run that manually when you make changes to your database or include it in a script you have to automate it somewhere before calling your view query.

Comment: I always thought executing ALTER VIEW with the same definition would refresh the view just as well as `sp_refreshview` does. It's just that the latter is more convenient to use.